# Getting Angular material fixed sidebar and header

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angular-material

My DOM structure goes like this:

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill>
 <header >Must be fixed</header>
 <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" layout="row" layout-fill>
  Sidenav should be fixed
 </md-sidenav>
 <div layout="column" layout-fill>
   <div>
     Main content
   </div>
 <footer>Sticky footer</footer>
</div>
```

I want a header and sidenav to be fixed, just like in angular material doc site. With a sticky footer also, what should be my basic approach?

Comment: Have you tried to set `md-is-locked-open` attribute? <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" ...

Comment: `display: fixed` in css should solve it? What have you tried, and what is it with your approach that didn't work?